# Revisiting "Degrees of freedom"

Tags: regression, degrees-of-freedom

In Eq.3 and Eq.4 of "effective degrees of freedom" [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.7851.pdf) Freedman defines degrees of freedom in terms of the difference between train loss and test loss, where train/test both use **the same** dataset $X$, but resample noisy labels $y$:

[image]

In practice however our train and test sets correspond to different $n\times p$ observation matrices $X1$, $X2$, so what measure of model complexity corresponds to this case?

For instance, if we let true parameter $\theta=(1,0,0,\ldots)$ be a vector of size $p$ and we draw $X1$ and $X2$ IID from a common distribution, then our test risk looks something like below for number of observations $n=10$

[image]

In some sense, the $p=100$ model is less sensitive to noise, so should be preferred over $p=10$ model when the number of observations is 10. On other hand, measures of model complexity like BIC, AIC are monotonically increasing with the number of parameters.

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-least-squares-overfitting.nb)